# Piping not working as expected with SCP

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, scp

I am trying to pass the password to scp command so that it doeskin prompt for it. I am doing it like this.

```
echo "pwd" | scp -r $files_path $user@$server:$target
```

On one server it is working fine but on other one it again prompts for a password.

Want I am doing wrong in the second scenario, pls help.

Comment: Use `sshpass` if you have to use password authentication and automate it

Comment: Also remember `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data and that in most Bourne-like shells, parameter expansions must be quoted.